# Send socket message to different UDP connections with same IP and port

Tags: sockets, ip, port, dji-sdk

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I'm trying to create a Python program that can control multiple Ryze Tello drones. These are very simple drones which can be controlled by connecting a computer to it through a Wi-Fi UDP port and sending through text commands.

For example, this is a simple program where, upon connecting to the drone's Wi-Fi network, it will simply send a command to 'takeoff' to the drone.

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto('command', 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
sock.sendto('takeoff', 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
```

Now, my goal is to be able to send commands to multiple such drones at once (for example, to have them perform a planned "dance" routine). I have multiple Wi-Fi dongles connected to my computer, each connected to an individual drone. However, the problem is that each drone has a fixed IP and port, shown above. I have attempted to SSH into the drone to change its IP, but no luck, and the support line was not sure if it was possible with the Tello. However, as the connections are still treated distinctly on my computer, there must be a way to send commands to the drones separately. As to how, I am unsure, hence why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate `socket` object for each drone, where each `socket` is `bind()`'ed to the local IP of a specific WiFi adapter that a drone is connected to. Then you can `sendto()` commands through each `socket` as needed. Even if the drones all have the same IP and port, the `bind`'s ensure that each command gets sent out over the appropriate WiFi network to the correct drone it is targeting.

Something like this:

```
import socket

sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock1.bind(('WiFi_1_IP', 8889));
sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock2.bind(('WiFi_2_IP', 8889));
sock3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock3.bind(('WiFi_3_IP', 8889));
...

sock1.sendto('command', 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
sock2.sendto('command', 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
sock3.sendto('command', 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
...

sock1.sendto('takeoff', 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
sock2.sendto('takeoff', 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
sock3.sendto('takeoff', 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
...
```